# can my Device ID # on my Android Samsung Epic be changed?

Tags: samsung-epic-4g

I was Banned from an App (for quoting Monty Python no less!) but want back in.  Is there a way to change my Device ID # so that I can start anew and sign up with the App again?  I don't want to get a new phone, and I'm not super techie, so if there is a way it has to either be relativly easy, or smeone I can ask to do it for me.  Thanks

Comment: What device ID?  IMEI?

Comment: If you're talking about IMEI I'd recommend against changing it. It's very easy to cause trouble to your service provider with duplicate IMEIs and tampering it can brick your phone.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe @Mark Dorsey is talking about the IMEI, I think he means the Device ID that android assigns to a device.

This ID is generated when the device first boots, but it will be recreated if you do a factory reset.

[Reference](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html)

> More specifically, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID. This is a 64-bit quantity that is generated and stored when the device first boots. It is reset when the device is wiped.
>
> ANDROID_ID seems a good choice for a unique device identifier. There are downsides: First, it is not 100% reliable on releases of Android prior to 2.2 (“Froyo”). Also, there has been at least one widely-observed bug in a popular handset from a major manufacturer, where every instance has the same ANDROID_ID.

With that said, there is no guarantee that the application you are looking to gain access again with uses the Device ID, it may use other means to identify the device, like mac address, or some other information, or even a combination of them.