# What info/data can a fresh installed app without permission gather?

Tags: security, installation, privacy, uninstallation, ads

1. If I just install an app BUT DON'T OPEN it, can it do/get something? Maybe during installation process, even if I didn't open it yet?
2. If I didn't give the app any permission, what can it do/know? Can it access to parts of my storage? What kind of information does it know? Can it get Imei, mac address, phone number, serial number?
3. I am asking this because I have Aliexpress that when I open it it shows my name and surname, EVEN IF I FRESH installed it and first time I open it. So HOW TF does it know????? If you think that there is an online google backup, it's not: I cleared data before opening it, and it still shows my name and surname. THE ONLY WAY I achieve not to show my name/surname is launching it via "CloneApp". HOW can Aliexpress achieve this? It's CREEPY.

Comment: you are using same ip address

Comment: if you purchase some app the app developer needs some way to track the purchase bounded to your mobile, therefore I am pretty sure every app can read your android ID (which afaik is concatenated with another ramdom string on per-app-base)

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/13876

Comment: What device identifiers can be accessed depends on the Android version. On recent versions (11+) no direct identifiers should be accessible anymore. If  the behavior changes via app cloner this could indicate that they have assigned your ANDROID_ID to your account. On modern devices every app is getting an "obfuscated" ANDROID_ID which is different (but constant) for every app.

Comment: @alecxs if I install an app but don't open it, can it open silently by itself and gather infos?

Comment: @Robert if I install an app but don't open it, can it open silently by itself and gather infos?

Comment: Not sure if this is still possible on Android 10/11/12 devices, but in general an app can register a service to be notified e.g. if the battery state changes, after reboot, if the device is connected to a power source and so on and then execute code. I think on modern Android versions you have to start the app at least once for making it possible to register such code handlers.